# Founding? Is it wrong or right?

Tags: grammar

One of my Japanese students said the following today when we were practicing for an MBA interview.

"I want to founding my own venture in the future"

I corrected it automatically to "I want to find my own venture...". Also, I felt that "launch" or "start" would be better than the verb "to find" since he was talking about his long-term goal.

When I said this to my student, they said that there is a verb "to found". But I think we can't say "I want to founding my business/venture/etc", no?

At least I've never heard this kind of sentence so I'm confused about what the student means ...

Can someone please enlighten me? Is the student wrong or am I just not getting something?

Comment: Related: ["Do we have *founded*?](/q/95647)

Answer (score 28):

**To found** is correct: [to set up or establish on a firm basis or for enduring existence](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/found).

But you should use the infinitive:

> I want to buy a book
>   I want to found a company

Not

> I want to buying a book
>   I want to founding a company

(Edit:) As [KRyan](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/367/kryan) notes in the comment below there is a third possibility:

> I want to be founding a company.

There is a slight difference in the meaning between the two. Using *want to found* implies that this is a thing you want to do at some point, *want to be founding* implies a particular point in time that you want to be involved in this process (e.g. "What do you see yourself doing in five years?" "I want to be founding a company.)"

Comment: Alternatively, *I was to **be** founding a company.* Slight difference in the meaning between the two—using *want to found* implies that this is a thing you want to do at some point, *want to be founding* implies a particular point in time that you want to be involved in this process (e.g. "What do you see yourself doing in five years?" "I want to be founding a company.")

Comment: Thank you so much! This comment really helped me. The explanation is very easy to understand.

Answer (score 6):

*To Found* is an infinitive (basic form of the verb) which means *To create or establish*, especially those things which have a continued existence e.g. a building.

When we say that a person is a ***Founder*** of this Company, or in the phrase that we keep the ***Foundation*** of a house, the infinitive form of the word Found is used.

Therefore, Founding a venture or business is grammatically correct. With an adjustment in the tense used, your correct sentence would be:

> I want to found my own venture in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The verb **to found** means

> establish or originate (an institution or organization)

Very briefly, in this instance **to found** is an infinitive, which can (and in this sentence, does) act as a noun, effectively the direct object of **want** in the sentence you cite.

The sentence **I want to found my own venture** is correct, although the word **venture** may be considered vague.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot use the term:

> I want to founding an adventure

you **can** still use:

> I am founding an adventure

As though you are currently in the process of doing this.

You can use this also:

> I founded an adventure

Being past tense. Although I personally wouldn't use this term as it would easily be passed as a misspelling of the sentence **I found an adventure**. A better option would be **I created an adventure** or **built an adventure**.

.